# Find camera connected to Macintosh in Terminal?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app, camera

Is it possible use the Terminal on Mac (OS X 10.6.8) to find a camera (Kodak EasyShare Z712 IS in this case) connected via USB? This camera does not show up in the Finder as a mounted drive. Where/How do applications like Image Capture & iPhoto find the images is there not somewhere on the computer's file system?